# Azure DevOps REST Interface - Can't get all builds with Builds LIST

Tags: rest, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-rest-api

I am trying to make a REST call to get all builds of a certain definition.  The problem is, I don't think it's getting the deleted items even though I'm asking for them.
There is no ContinuationToken in the response before someone asks, this seems to be the full list.

I get 224 results from the REST call.  **BUT** if I go to the pipeline analytics page, I see there were 632 runs for that time period([https://dev.azure.com/{{organization}}/{{project}}/_pipeline/analytics/stageawareoutcome?definitionId=14&contextType=build](https://dev.azure.com/%7B%7Borganization%7D%7D/%7B%7Bproject%7D%7D/_pipeline/analytics/stageawareoutcome?definitionId=14&contextType=build)).

Now, I expect that most of these builds have since expired since we have a 30 day retention policy.
But clearly the analytics page has access to more data than my REST query is returning.
Is there any way to get at the data that that is missing?
I presume the delta is the builds that have since expired due to our 30 day retention policy, but hoping that since analytics knows about them, there's a way for me to get at it too.
Setting the deletedFilter=includeDeleted doesn't seem to have done the job.

Here's what I'm using for my call:

[https://dev.azure.com/{{organization}}/{{project}}/_apis/build/builds?api-version=7.0&queryOrder=queueTimeAscending&deletedFilter=includeDeleted&maxBuildsPerDefinition=1000&minTime=2022-09-01&definitions=14](https://dev.azure.com/%7B%7Borganization%7D%7D/%7B%7Bproject%7D%7D/_apis/build/builds?api-version=7.0&queryOrder=queueTimeAscending&deletedFilter=includeDeleted&maxBuildsPerDefinition=1000&minTime=2022-09-01&definitions=14)

Answer (score 0):

So, never did get the REST call to give me all the data I wanted, but the OData route gave me what I needed.  I created a data source in Power BI instead using the guidance here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/powerbi/sample-pipelines-outcome-summary?view=azure-devops&tabs=powerbi

That did give me the whole set of data that was showing up in the ADO pipelines analytics page.